# Prove that there are infinitely many primes in $Q[ √ d]$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that there are infinitely many primes in $Q[ √ d]$.

I have evaluated other solutions for this question, but am looking for a simple approach that preferably don't extensively involve the notions of rings or fields. Apparently, the proof almost identical to the
proof that there are infinitely many primes in $Z$. I haven't been able to make any progress on this approach. Does anyone see a solution in their number theory wisdom?

Note: I believe what is referred to as primes in this question, we commonly know as irreducibles. A painful inconsistency.

**Edit: I believe I may have got it. Can someone confirm?**

Suppose $π_1,...π_k$ are all of these irreducibles. We then consider $N(π_1⋅⋯⋅π_k)+1$ and what must divide it.

$N(π_1⋅π_2⋯π_N)+1$  has an irreducible non-unit factor $α$, and $α$ cannot be a unit times one of the $π_i$. For if $α$ was a unit times some $π_i$, then $α$ would divide $π_1⋯π_n$, so $α$ would divide 1, contradicting the fact $α$ is not a unit. Hence, there are infinitely many irreducibles in $Q[√d]$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ is a field, there are no primes.  Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$?  Or do you mean the ring of integers in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$?

Comment: When I say primes, I mean irreducibles. From some reason, the book I found this question in uses those two interchangeably.

Comment: In a field, irreducible and prime are the same thing, and neither exist.

Comment: Wait I'm sorry, I must have read through your first comment too carelessly. I should believe it is the ring of integers. According to the book I found this question in, it is similar (almost identical) to the proof there are infinitely primes in $Z[√d]$, however, which seems contradictory.

Comment: Why contradictory?

Comment: Ugh. I've been quite overwhelmed with other things, and it seems like I was distracted even when typing a comment. Please excuse that statement.